# Probability of real roots

Tags: probability

Let's take random $a, b \in [0,2] $.

What is a probability that equation $ax^2+bx+1=0$ has two real roots?

My solution:

$\Delta = b^2-4a>0$

$a< \frac{b^2}{4}$

$P( \Omega) = 2 *2=4$

$\mathrm{P}(A) = \int^2_0 \frac{b^2}{4}\mathrm{d}b$

and the answer is $\frac{\mathrm{P}(A)}{\mathrm{P}(\Omega)}$

Is it correct?

Comment: Why does $\Delta > 0$ result in _integer_ roots?  Real roots, yes; but _integer_ roots?

Comment: If you mean that $a$, $b$ have **continuous** uniform distribution on $[0,2]$ the probability is $0$.

Comment: Sorry! The question is real roots! My mistake...

Comment: Is it correct right now?

Comment: Not the title. $ $

Comment: Now the title is ok, but what about solution??

Comment: @AndréNicolas why y looks like that? I don't get it.

Comment: Well... One should probably squirm learning that P(Ω)=4.

Comment: We want the probability that if $A$ and $B$ are the random variables (I prefer caps) then $B^2\gt 4A$. The "good" part of the square therefore has $(A,B)$ landing in the region I described. I am assuming that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: @Did 4 is not correct? It's because 2-0 * 2-0 because $a,b \in [0,2]$

Comment: @AndréNicolas ok, I see but could I take $y=\frac{b^2}{4}$ and draw a graph of a? Is it a different?

Comment: You could certainly interchange variable, I just visualized $A$ along the $x$-axis and $B$ along the $y$-axis for alphabetic reasons only. Whatever you do, the area/integration problem will be essentially the same.

Comment: So my solution is ok?

Comment: Thanks for advice. I did it and I think that limits of my integral were wrong. Correct from 0 to 1. So solution of my integral is $\frac{1}{12}$ So solution of the exercises is $\frac{1}{48} $?

Comment: Oh I think it's something wrong....

Comment: Apart from notation confusion, you may have had the right geometric idea. A picture will tell you what you must integrate over.

Comment: Your original limits were right.

Comment: This is how my graph: http://oi58.tinypic.com/2vvkj2a.jpg
I feel lost right now and have no idea about the answer...

Comment: What you have indicated above is correct, once you change $P(A)$ and $P(\Omega)$ to $\text{Area}(A)$ and $\text{Area}(\Omega)$, so your answer should be $\frac{2/3}{4}=\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: @user84413 but in your case limits are from 0 to 2. I think 1 is correct. It shows on my graph.

Comment: I believe that $a$ varies from 0 to 1, but $b$ varies from 0 to 2; so you could use $\int_{0}^2\frac{b^2}{4}db$ or $\int_{0}^{1}(2-2\sqrt{a})da$.

Comment: You're right!
Thanks, I think now it is clear:)

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit more transparent to convert to the Uniform(0, 1) distribution rather than use Uniform(0, 2). Given the setup, we have

$P\big(a < \frac{b^2}{4}\big) \Longleftrightarrow P\big(a^* < \frac{b^{*2}}{2}\big)$

where $a^* = \frac{a}{2}$ and $b^* = \frac{b}{2}$ are from independent Uniform(0, 1) distributions.

Then $P\big(a^* < \frac{b^{*2}}{2}\big)$ is simply the proportion of the unit square for which
$a^* < \frac{b^{*2}}{2}$ which is

$\int_0^1 \frac{b^{*2}}{2}db^*$ = $[\frac{1}{6}b^{*3}]_0^1$ = $\frac{1}{6}$

(in agreement with your result).